# How to get exception StackTrace for reflected assemblies in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a simple c# .net windows service, which loads assemblies at run time and execute a method in it. If there is an error I send an email to myself with a stack trace in it. Problem is stack trace only gives me stack of my program and not of the reflected assembly. Is there a way to get that. Here is the code

```
try
{
  var filename = "abc.dll";
  var assemblyToLoad = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);
  var args = new object[]
                        {
                         "FirstName","LastName"
                        };

  var classToLoad = assemblyToLoad.CreateInstance("abc.myclass", false,
                BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, args, null, null);

  var value = classToLoad.GetType().GetMethod("Run").Invoke(classToLoad, null);

}

catch(Exception ex)
{

  SendMail(ex.StackTrace);

}
```

Comment: You probably need the InnerException from the Exception you're catching: `ex.InnerException.StackTrace`.

Comment: This might work. Thanks dartnow. I will try and post it when I know for sure.

Comment: Never do this, use ex.ToString() so you get *all* the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dartonw. His suggestion worked. I feel stupid. I just have to drop the .pdb file of the reflected assembly into the bin folder and look at the innerException's stack trace to get the stack trace of the reflected assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to reinvent the wheel, why have this basic way of logging when you could implement a well known and strong framework?

May i suggest you take a look at [Elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) it's one of the easiest logging frameworks I have used.

Comment: How did you use in a windows application? My app is a windows service.  I thought elmah is used for web application logging.

Comment: I am unsure, I have only used Elmah for web applications.  You could try other well known frameworks like Log4Net and NLog, I know they will be compatible with non-web based applications.